# Is there a first-order supertheory of linearly ordered commutative rings whose "only" model is the integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, first-order-logic

My apologies if my question is ill-formed, since I have little background in mathematical logic; any suggestions would be welcome.

---

Given a signature $\Sigma$ and two first-order theories $T,T'$ on $\Sigma$, suppose $T$ is a sub-theory of $T'$.
Then, since every model (in Sets) of $T'$ should also be a model of $T$, and homomorphisms of $T'$-models should also be homomorphisms of $T$-models, we should get an induced functor $\mathcal{M}' \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ from the category of models of $T'$ to that of $T$.

We consider the following case:

- $\Sigma$ is the signature for two distinguished terms, two binary operations, and one binary relation;
- and $T$ is the theory of linearly ordered commutative rings.
- So then, $\mathcal{M}$ is canonically the category of linearly ordered commutative rings.

I was wondering, in the above scenario:

> Is it possible to find $T'$ such that the essential image of the functor $\mathcal{M}'\rightarrow \mathcal{M}\cong\mathrm{LinOrdCommRings}$ is just (the iso class of) $\mathbb{Z}$? If not, how is this shown?

---

I was reading [Lecture 1](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/278xnotes/Lecture1-Overview.pdf) of Dr. Lurie's [lecture notes](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/278x.html) on Categorical Logic, and in Warning 7 there, he gives a description of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is second-order. He doesn't directly explain whether a first-order description is possible; however, from what I understand, his next explanation about the impossibility of writing a computer program to generate all statements about $\mathbb{Z}$ would imply that $\mathbb{Z}$ cannot have a first-order description?

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In general any first order theory that has infinite models will not be categorical. In fact by Lowenheim Skolem you have that for any cardinal $\kappa\geq \aleph_0$ there is a model of that size. This follows easily from the compactness theorem. In fact If I take $T$ to be the theory of all true first order statements of $\mathbb{Z}$ then I have that it too has models that are not countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the **[compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem)** (in its guise as the [upward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Upward_part)) annihilates any hope of doing this at all: any theory $T$ with an infinite model has infinite models of arbitrarily large cardinality. In particular, any theory which has a model with $\mathbb{Z}$ as a "ring-reduct" also has an uncountable model whose ring-reduct will of course not be $\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

But **it gets worse**! Maybe you say "OK fine, we'll have unwanted uncountable models, but can we at least have just one *countable* model (up to isomorphism)?" Here compactness ... actually still works (assuming we restrict attention to countable languages), once we combine it with another result: the **[downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Downward_part)**. If $\mathcal{R}$ is an uncountable ring, then it must have a non-Archimedean element $a$ (indeed, many) - now apply dLS to get a countable elementary substructure $\mathcal{S}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{R}$ which is non-Archimedean and so not $\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!